# How can I remove the leading path from a tar and retar it in memory?

Tags: download, path, tar

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
wget -O- http://example.com/funky.tar.gz | \
  tar --strip-components 1 -Ox | tar -cf fixed.tar.gz
```

to remove the leading path from all items in the downloaded tar, but it appears that there is no way to create a tar from stdin. Please prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You most certainly can create a tar from stdin. Use `-` as the source, and pipe whatever you want to tar into it.

http://ss64.com/bash/tar.html

http://www.google.com/search?q=tar+stdin

Comment: I think I've gotten a bit further. I tried testing with this intermediate command:

    cat cookbooks.tar.gz | tar -xO --strip-components 1 | tar -cf recipe.tar @-

But I get this error:
tar: Error reading archive (null): Unrecognized archive format: Inappropriate file type or format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Comment: You don't use `@-`, rather you use - as the input, as in `tar -cf recipe.tar -`

Comment: Read all of this: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still stuck after reading it though. Perhaps an example? I tried `tar -Oxf cookbooks.tar.gz | tar -cf recipe.tar -` but I get this error: "tar: no files or directories specified". When I look at the output of tar -Oxf cookbooks.tar.gz it does not have file and directory names, just the content of the files.

Comment: @Michael: What you want is basically a tarpipe, minus the SSH: http://www.google.com/search?q=tar+pipe+ssh

Answer (score 2):

The Python [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) module supports both stream reading and writing. You can take the result of [`TarFile.extractfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) from one tar file and feed it right into [`TarFile.addfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.addfile) of a second file. Obviously this would require a bit of programming, but it would do as you ask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that one might describe what you want as a “stream editor” for *tar* files that allows you to apply the `--strip-components` pathname translation. The idea is to take a *tar* file as input and write a modified *tar* file as output.

None of the *tar*﻿s who's documentation I checked ([GNU *tar*](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html), [*star*](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/star/star.1.html), [*bsdtar*](http://people.freebsd.org/~kientzle/libarchive/man/bsdtar.1.txt)) seem to support your exact operation.

*bsdtar* is interesting though. Its `@archive` syntax seems like it would come close to letting you read a tarfile and write a modified one, but the manpage entry for `--strip-components` says that it only works in `x` and `t` modes). If it did work in `c` mode, you could use something like this:

```
wget -O - <url> | bsdtar -c --strip-components 1 -zf new.tar.gz @-
```

I do not have *bsdtar* on my machine (it is [*tar* in FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=1&format=html), as well as [*tar* in Mac OS X 10.6](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html) (older releases use GNU *tar*); it is available as *bsdtar* on some Linux distributions: [Debian GNU/Linux](http://packages.debian.org/sid/bsdtar), [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/bsdtar), and [some RPM-based distributions](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=bsdtar)), but looking at the code, I am sure that invocation will just cause an “Option --strip-components is not permitted in mode -c” error.

If you want this, you will probably have to roll your own program (or get someone to do it for you). Fortunately, this may not be as hard as it sounds. *bsdtar* is based on the very nice [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/) library. It looks like it would be fairly straightforward to make a program that does what you want. Since *bsdtar* already has most of the code you would need to copy one archive to another (through its `@archive` handling), you could probably even do it by adding some functionality to *bsdtar*. An simple “damn the architecture, just get it done” approach might be to enable `--strip-components` for `c` mode and add a call to [`edit_pathname`](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/source/browse/trunk/tar/util.c) inside [`append_archive`](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/source/browse/trunk/tar/write.c). The problem with this approach is that all the `edit_pathname` transformations would be applied to both entries from `@archive`s and the pathnames of actual files specified through other means (command line args, `-T` pathname lists, etc.). This behavior may or may not in the best interest of official *bsdtar* (there is probably some reason `--strip-components` is not already enabled for `c` mode).